# Please help solve a bank's maximization problem

Tags: macroeconomics, monetary-policy

I want to solve following maximization problem:

$\underset{\{i_{t}^{l}(i),i_{t}^{d}(i),B_{t}^{l}(i),B_{t}^{d}(i),R_{t}(i)\}}{\max }
i_{t}^{r}R_{t}(i)+(i_{t}^{l}(i)-\mu ^{l})
B_{t}^{l}(i)-(i_{t}^{d}(i)
-\mu ^{d})B_{t}^{d}(i)-\Gamma(B^{l}_{t}(i), Z_{t}(i))$

where $i_{t}^{r}$ is reserve rate. $i_{t}^{l}(i)$ is bank $i$'s lending rate and $i_{t}^{d}(i)$ is bank $i$'s deposit rate.
$R_{t}(i)$, $Z_{t}(i)$, $B_{t}^{l}(i)$, and $B_{t}^{d}(i)$ are bank $i$'s reserves, profits, loans, and deposits, respectively. $\mu^{l}$ denote cost of issuing loans and $\mu^{d}$ denote benefit of receiving deposits. $\Gamma(B^{l}_{t}(i), Z_{t}(i))$ is an intermediation cost that is a function of $B^{l}_{t}(i), Z_{t}(i)$.

bank $i$ is faced with following nominal constraint.
\begin{equation}
B_{t}^{l}(i)\leq (\frac{1+i^{l}_{t}(i)}{1+i^{l}_{t}})^{-\varepsilon ^{l}}B_{t}^{l}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  B_{t}^{d}(i)=\left\{
  \begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    (\frac{1+i_{t}^{d}(i)}{1+i^{d}_{t}})^{-\varepsilon ^{d}}B_{t}^{d} & \text{if}\ i^{d}_{t}(i)\geq 0 \\
    0 & \text{if}\ i^{d}_{t}(i)< 0
  \end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
(1+i_{t}^{d}(i))B^{d}_{t}(i)=(1+i_{t}^{l}(i)-\mu^{l})B^{l}_{t}(i)+(1+i_{t}^{r})R_{t}(i)+\mu^{d}B^{d}_{t}(i)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
R_{t}(i) \geq 0
\end{equation}

where (19) is a loan demand constraint and (20) is a deposit demand constraint. (21) is a zero net worth constraint. (22) is non-negative reserve requirement.

I want to verify whether the solutions are

\begin{equation}
1+i_{t}^{d}(i)=\frac{\varepsilon^{d}}{\varepsilon^{d}-1}(1+i_{t}^{r} +\mu^{d})
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
1+i_{t}^{l}(i)=\frac{\varepsilon ^{l}}{\varepsilon ^{l}-1}(1+i_{t}^{r}+\mu
^{l})+\frac{\varepsilon ^{l}}{\varepsilon ^{l}-1}(1+i_{t}^{r})\Gamma
_{B_{t}^{l}(i)}
\end{equation}

Any help would really be appreciated! Thank you